# How do I access data passed from a query in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

How do I get the data that should be passed back from this query. This is in my model. I don't know if i'm doing this right since I haven't gotten back any output. I have already tested the query in phpmyadmin and it works. I need to be able to pass data from `function get_reg2()` to my controller successfully.

I don't know if the return is doing it right

```
return $this->db->query($query, $data); 

Joins_model extends CI_Model....
function get_reg2($data){
$query = ('

SELECT DISTINCT
    cm_valuacion.mano_obra,
    cm_nomina.nomina,
    cm_empleado.nombre,
    cm_proveedor.nombre,
    cm_valuacion.hojalateria,
    cm_valuacion.pintura,
    cm_valuacion.mecanica,
    cm_valuacion.refaccion,
    cm_valuacion.tipo,
    cm_valuacion.shojalateria,
    cm_valuacion.spintura,
    cm_valuacion.smecanica,
    cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria,
    cm_valuacion.costoPintura,
    cm_valuacion.costoMecanica,
    cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria,
    cm_valuacion.pv_pintura,
    cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica,
    cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria,
    cm_valuacion.pc_pintura,
    cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica,
    cm_compras.precio,
    cm_compras.status
FROM cm_valuacionr,
    cm_nomina
INNER JOIN cm_empleado
    ON cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id
INNER JOIN cm_valuacion
    ON cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = cm_nomina.id_siniestro
INNER JOIN cm_compras
    ON cm_compras.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro
INNER JOIN cm_proveedor
    ON cm_compras.id_proveedor = cm_proveedor.id
WHERE cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = ?
    AND cm_valuacion.id_complemento = 0
GROUP BY mano_obra
    ');
return $this->db->query($query, $data);

}

}
```

also I don't know if im receiving it correctly here

```
 $registros = $this->joins_model->get_reg2($id);
```

what I have in my controller is:

```
$registros = $this->joins_model->get_reg2($id);
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
    $this->table->set_heading(
        $this->st_cell('D'),
        $this->st_cell('CANT.'),
        $this->st_cell('PROVEEDOR'),
        $this->st_cell('NOTA'),
        $this->st_cell('DESCRIPCION'),
        $this->st_cell('COSTO'),
        $this->st_cell('VENTA'),
        $this->st_cell('EMPLEADO'),
        $this->st_cell('NOMINA'),
        $this->st_cell('TOTAL')
    );

    foreach ($registros->result() as $registro){
        //this is where I want to be able to specify what parameter I want               
        //to access from the query that was returned. How do I do this?
        //for example theres *nombre* up there and it's there twice. Once
        //for *empleado* and the other for *proveedor*
    }
```

and using it correctly here;

```
$registros->result() as $registro
```

Comment: what do you get if you `var_dump($registro);` inside the foreach? if it says 'array' you can do `echo $registro['column'];` if it says 'object' you can `echo $registro->column;`

Comment: what is the output you gets with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions

> 1. In Model `get_reg2($id)` I assumed data is receiving.
> 2. Your SQL code is working fine.

**Changes**

> 1. Model code Modified, with returning objective array.
> 2. Controller Function changed.
> 3. Table heading modified.
> 4. `foreach` loop pointed with data to present.

**Reefer**

1. [HTML Table Class in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html)

---

Try this

**In Model**

```
function get_reg2($id)
{
    $query = ('
        SELECT DISTINCT
            cm_valuacion.mano_obra,
            cm_nomina.nomina,
            cm_empleado.nombre,
            cm_proveedor.nombre,
            cm_valuacion.hojalateria,
            cm_valuacion.pintura,
            cm_valuacion.mecanica,
            cm_valuacion.refaccion,
            cm_valuacion.tipo,
            cm_valuacion.shojalateria,
            cm_valuacion.spintura,
            cm_valuacion.smecanica,
            cm_valuacion.costoHojalateria,
            cm_valuacion.costoPintura,
            cm_valuacion.costoMecanica,
            cm_valuacion.pv_hojalateria,
            cm_valuacion.pv_pintura,
            cm_valuacion.pv_mecanica,
            cm_valuacion.pc_hojalateria,
            cm_valuacion.pc_pintura,
            cm_valuacion.pc_mecanica,
            cm_compras.precio,
            cm_compras.status
        FROM cm_valuacionr,
            cm_nomina
        INNER JOIN cm_empleado
            ON cm_nomina.id_empleado = cm_empleado.id
        INNER JOIN cm_valuacion
            ON cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = cm_nomina.id_siniestro
        INNER JOIN cm_compras
            ON cm_compras.id_siniestro = cm_valuacion.id_siniestro
        INNER JOIN cm_proveedor
            ON cm_compras.id_proveedor = cm_proveedor.id
        WHERE cm_valuacion.id_siniestro = ?
            AND cm_valuacion.id_complemento = 0
        GROUP BY mano_obra
            ');
        $query =  $this->db->query($query, $id); # Changed
        $result = $query->result_array(); # Added
        return $result; # Added
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$registros = $this->joins_model->get_reg3($id);
//var_dump($registros);
//print_r($registros);
if (empty($registros))
{
    echo "No data recived from Database";
}else{

    ?>
    <table border="2px">
    <tr>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>Cant</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($registros as $registro)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $registro['mano_obra'] ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $registro['nomina'] ?></td> 
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: so it would be $registro['fisrt_table_field _name'], which would be $registro['cm_valuacion.mano_obra'],... am I right in thinking this?

Comment: im seeing that `$registros[0] as $registro` gives me only the first character of the array that comes back in registros @Abdulla

Comment: @learningbyexample before `if` add this `print_r($registros)` and comment all below code and post the array of data

Comment: `var_dump($registros);
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=23)
      'mano_obra' => string 'CAMBIO DE RADIADOR' (length=18)
      'nomina' => string '89.00000000000000' (length=17)
      'empleado' => string 'DAVID' (length=5)
      'proveedor' => string 'proveedor' (length=8)
      'hojalateria' => string '' (length=0)
      'pintura' => string '' (length=0)
      'mecanica' => string '250' (length=3)
      'refaccion' => string 'REDIADOR' (length=8)
      'tipo' => string '' (length=0)
      'shojalateria' => string '' (length=0)
      'spintura' => string '' (length=0)`

Comment: Not var dump. Use `print_r($registros)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111662/discussion-between-learningbyexample-and-abdulla).